# Replacing regex with the same amount of "." as its length

Tags: java, regex

See this for my current attempt: http://regexr.com?374vg

I have a regex that captures what I want it to capture, the thing is that the `String().replaceAll("regex", ".")` replaces everything with just one `.`, which is fine if it's at the end of the line, but otherwise it doesn't work.

How can I replace every character of the match with a dot, so I get the same amount of `.` symbols as its length?

Comment: What are you tyrying to do ?

Comment: He's trying to replace every character in the match with a literal dot

Comment: Trying to replace `COG-192029` (which has a different amount of number characters in different cases) with the correct amount of `.` symbols i.e. `COG-1` => `.....`

Comment: What characters are you matching?  Might not be a job for regex, but maybe a substring instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a one line solution:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=COG-\\d{0,99})\\d", ".").replaceAll("COG-(?=\\.+)", "....");
```

Here's some test code:

```
String str = "foo bar COG-2134 baz";
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=COG-\\d{0,99})\\d", ".").replaceAll("COG-(?=\\.+)", "....");
System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

```
foo bar ........ baz
```

Comment: Very nice, sadly it doesn't work for more than 10 digits after `COG-`, though I doubt there is ever a possibility to get more than 10 digits after `COG-` I'm gonna use another solution. Thanks though this one is great!

Comment: In addition it will replace "COG-. " in the input by "....." which may not be intended. But in general a great solution!

Comment: @Schadenfreude well that's easily solved - just change the "9" to "99" (or even larger if you need). BTW, the reason you need a range is you can't have just "+" because look-behinds must have a maximum length.

Comment: @MarkusKreusch see previous comment just made, but yes you have noticed the small weakness, however it's only a problem if the character sequence `COG-.` (ie including the dot) appears in the original string. I couldn't think of a way around this yet stillnkeep the code short, but thought it was an acceptable gap and I hoped no one would notice :)

Comment: @Schadenfreude oh and I also changed the answer to accommodate larger numeric sequences (now it will find up to 99 digit numbers)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible using String#replaceAll. You might be able to use Pattern.compile(regexp) and iterate over the matches like so:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);
int previous = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
    result.append(inputString.substring(previous, matcher.start()));
    result.append(buildStringWithDots(matcher.end() - matcher.start()));
    previous = matcher.end();
}
result.append(inputString.substring(previous, inputString.length()));
```

To use this you have to define `buildStringWithDots(int length)` to build a String containing `length` dots.

Comment: Would you know how to write the same code in Visual Basic ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("COG-([0-9]+)");
Matcher mt = p.matcher("Fixed. Added ''Show annualized values' chackbox in EF Comp Report. Also fixed the problem with the missing dots for the positions and the problem, described in COG-18613");
if (mt.find()) {
    char[] array = new char[mt.group().length()];
    Arrays.fill(array, '.');
    System.out.println( " <=> " + mt.replaceAll(new String(array)));
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

`Fixed. Added ''Show annualized values' chackbox in EF Comp Report. Also fixed the problem with the missing dots for the positions and the problem, described in .........`

Comment: @MarkusKreusch: Can you elaborate on your comment?

Comment: You use a matcher to search for the pattern and then invoke find which finds the first occurence of COG-([0-9]+). You create a String containing '.' which has the length of the first match. Then you replace ALL matches with this string. So if you use your example this will be OK. But using "COG-1 COG-123456" will create "..... ....." which is not correct.
So as long as the input contains only one occurrence everything is fine. If you have multiple an approach like my answer will work.

Comment: Of course if there are multiple matches when `while` should be used, I just wanted to showcase the idea to OP. OP can take it forward from here.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd simplify your life and just do something like this (for starters).  I'll let you finish.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String cog = "COG-19708";

        for (int i = cog.indexOf("COG-"); i < cog.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println(cog.substring(i,i+1));
            // build new string
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you put your regex in grouping so replace it with string that matches the length of matched grouping? Something like:

```
regex = (_what_i_want_to_match)
String().replaceAll(regex, create string that has that many '.' as length of $1)
```

?

note: $1 is what you matched in your search

see also: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html