# Tricky Regex - Replace only the first occurrence and not the next occurence

Tags: java, regex

Need to match and replace all first occurrences of plus alone with %2b

Example

```
Input        Output
++123++      %2b%2b123++
+++++12      %2b%2b%2b%2b%2b12
12           12
123+         123+
+1           %2b1
+2           %2b2
```

How to do this via regex? It is possible to do via character matching in java but wanted to see whether it is possible via regex pattern?

`System.out.println("+++123".replaceFirst("\\+", "%2b"));` ==> Just removes the first character alone

Comment: So you want to replace only leading `+`, right? What about the trailing `+` in the first example, why did they vanish? What's the logic there? What's the expected output of the input `+1+2+`?

Comment: sorry, edited @JoachimSauer. +1 it would be %2b1 and for +2 it would be %2b2

Comment: You need `"^\\++"`. `^` to indicate "at the start of the input" and the last `+` to mean "one or more of what came before".

Comment: @JoachimSauer System.out.println("+++123".replaceFirst("^\\\\++", "%2b")); doesn't work

Comment: I m checking out other similar questions, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19908722/10671013) should be a good reference

Comment: @TanYuHauSean That also looks complex. Is any solution by iteration of character?

Comment: it uses Pattern and Matcher, but it still is regex.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to do this with a single regular expresion?  Why not write a simple loop instead of a complex regex?

Answer (score 3):

This is a great use case for `\G` - which matches the beginning of the string or at the position the previous match ended:

```
System.out.println("+++123++".replaceAll("\\G\\+", "%2b"));
```

Here's another option that is more easily expandable:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
...

String result = Pattern.compile("^\\++").matcher("+++123++")
                     .replaceAll(mr -> URLEncoder.encode(mr.group()).toLowerCase());
```

Here we're using an overload of [relpaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.Function)) that takes a callback and can dynamically calculate the result string, and [URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) to get the right number of pluses.

Comment: I used a deprecated overload of `URLEncoder.encode` because checked exceptions make this code way too long.

Comment: You can add a charset parameter to URLEncoder.encode without adding the try/catch.  Let other people worry about exactly how to deal with exceptions.